# Jackson objectMapper readValue on String of JSON Array - ignore errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a JSON array with some objects which are not of my class methods and I want to ignore them / catch them, this is how my JSON look:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John"
}, {
   "badItem": true
}]
```

and I'm running the code to convert the above string to my class (with `id` and `name` fields), like this:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            personList = objectMapper.readValue(msg, new TypeReference<List<Person>>() {});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("De-Serialization failed", e);
            response.addErrorMsg(e.toString());
        }
```

All my read will fail because of one bad item. How I can catch only the bad items and parse only the objects from the list that can work? (e.g John and catch badItem)

Comment: can you add the model class and the offending JSON?

Comment: @fantaghirocco The offending class is the "badItem", with is not a Person.

Comment: You will need a custom `JsonDeserializer`, maybe `DeserializationProblemHandler` also.

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties
You can `configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)`

I assume it will create empty objects for "bad items" that you might need to filter out later..